# With Phonegap, which is better: multiple html pages or multiple jquery-mobile pages?

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

As the title say, Which is better, multiple html pages or multiple jquery-mobile pages?

To emphasize:

What I mean by **multiple html pages** is that an app that starts with index.html and as you navigate with your app, it will change the visible page (via href) to other html pages like for example another.html, anotherone.html, anothertwo.html and so on.

What I mean by **multiple jquery-mobile pages** is like this [one](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/multipage-template.html).

Additionally, what I mean **better** is in terms of starting speed of the app, loading speed per page, installer/app size, memory consumption.

Comment: good question. many developers forgot to consider `performance vs resource consumption`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but there are things to consider when loading a "multiple jquery-mobile pages".

Cons of "multiple pages" case:

- do you need dynamic content in the pages? This would need to reload the whole multiple pages each time.
- how often do you update (I mean in application update to provide more detailed content for ex.) the pages? It is less convenient to update a page among many pages from one file, and CSS/XPath could be messy if you need fancy UI display (like relative/absolute kind of `position` of component
- very large page would take longer to load (but you'd need to actually test on various device to see the real impact and a "Loading" first page could make the trick).

In term of app size, I can't say here, but my feeling is that it wouldn't change much to have 1 page or multiple page. However having 1 big file would give difficulty (i.e. lower performance) to the device with less RAM.

My personal preference would go to several pages unless the content is really small and not dynamic (i.e. depends on user input/action).

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the right thinking. Great point and this is what I really looking for, a pros and cons. Well I guess my question is still a per case basis. I just want to know what to consider whenever I build an app using phonegap. Anyone care to add some more points?

Comment: You're welcome. Note this is not specific to phonegap only, but applies to any mobile website in general

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a huge app. There are more than 20 view pages and each one has to write heavy data into database, processing huge data etc.

Because of this, the design has to be limited to multiple HTML pages.

Putting it into multiple JQuery Mobile pages would have made the code too bloated and unmanageable. So in return for this, there is a visible visual lag when transitioning between pages (and most likely will not qualify for Apple Store. Luckily we are developing for the Android).